# Is there anyway to install pfsense on raspberry by using linux distro as base OS?

Tags: linux

I need to run pfsense on raspberry pi but since the architectures are different is there any possibility if i install some linux OS on raspberry and run pfsense on that linux OS.

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50321/can-you-run-pfsense-on-a-raspberry-pi-3

Comment: Duplicate of [Can you run pfsense on a Raspberry Pi 3?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50321/can-you-run-pfsense-on-a-raspberry-pi-3)